# PHP CheckStyle: Can't configure indentation

Tags: php, checkstyle

I am trying to use [phpcheckstyle](http://code.google.com/p/phpcheckstyle/). I can't figure out how to configure it for functional brackets on a new line (using 4 spaces for indentation):

```
1. class MyClass
2. {
3.     public function __construct()
4.     {
5.         // do something
6.     }
7. }
```

It always gives the error "The indentation level must be 8 but was 4." for line 4 and 6. It only allows one of the following:

```
1. class MyClass
2. {
3.     public function __construct() {
4.         // do something
5.     }
6. }
```

or

```
1. class MyClass
2. {
3.     public function __construct()
4.         {
5.         // do something
6.         }
7. }
```

If there a way to get around this or another PHP style checker than can understand this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for that, it was a bug.

It should be corrected with the latest version.

I personally only use tabs for indentation and I haven't tested enough. Please feel free to report any problem on the project page.